# How to give POST access to custom made api in woocommerce but keep api persmission readable only

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce

I made a custom api for woocommerce that handles everything for /cart url. But the problem is that in order to make http post to work I have to change the api permission to writable in the woocommerce settings this causes a big security problem. So my question is how can I keep the permission to readable only but give writable access to only /cart url?

`class-wc-api-cart.php`

```
class WC_API_Cart extends WC_API_Resource{

    protected $base = '/cart';

    public function register_routes( $routes ) {

        $routes[ $this->base ] = array(
            array( array( $this, 'get_cart' ), WC_API_Server::READABLE ),
        );

        $routes[ $this->base . '/update' ] = array(
            array( array( $this, 'update_cart' ), WC_API_SERVER::CREATABLE | WC_API_Server::ACCEPT_DATA ),
        );

        return $routes;
    }
```

The `WC_API_SERVER:CREATBLE` only works if I have the permission inside woocommerce api settings set to writeable.